# Qt How can get partition id?

Tags: linux, windows, qt, disk-partitioning

How can I get the partition id in Qt?

I'm searching for a good way to keep file directory without the partition name

For example, I want to save the directory of a file that is in my flash memory. in my computer maybe it's "Local Disc (F:)", and in another computer maybe it's "Local Disc (G:)", and if I keep the file directory with local disc name, i'm in a wrong way.

That's because i'm searching for another way, and I want to get the partition id and save the directory with partition id.

Can anyone help? Does anyone have a better idea? :)

I'm trying to do it in linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

Every used the [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html) class? You can use that to get the absolute path and then cut the resulting string on the first `/` and you will be left with the partition only.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to save the path without driver name just when it is in a portable device, if my directory be in my pc drivers, I want to save the full path. how can i make a difference between two things?